# Linux on a Dell Inspiron 630m

Tags: linux, debian, firmware, gparted

I have an old Dell Inspiron 630m with Windows XP and I want to put some Linux distro on it. I have tried Ubuntu 12 but it did not work (nothing happend). Downloading older versions is slow. I am not a nerd (only wanabe) so I'm afraid of installations that are more complicated than Ubuntu. But the old laptop is a great tool for messing up so I ask you, which distro should I try and how can I get it.

EDIT:
I went for Debian (Crunchbag looked nice but too big step for me from Ubuntu). I deleted Windows in GPARTED but now I'm missing firmware, `ipw2200-bss.fw`. How do I add it to my dead laptop?

Comment: Great! The cable saved me. Debian small CD and GPARTED with help from you and [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQpA6uiTpwg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From what I found](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/dell-inspiron-630m-14/4507-3121_7-31609787.html), this laptop is powerful enough to run a lightweight GUI (like XFCE, Openbox etc...).

You could start using Debian (which isn't much more complicated than Ubuntu) or Arch Linux (which is more difficult, but will be a good experience).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [CrunchBang](http://crunchbang.org/). Like Ubuntu, it is based on Debian, however, it uses the [Openbox](http://openbox.org/) window manager and in turn is significantly lighter on resources. I can't tell you specifically how well it will work on an Inspiron 630m, but it is definitely a solid distro. The project lead, [Philip Newborough](http://corenominal.org/), has done an incredible job of blending simplicity, beauty, and a "just works" functionality.

Here are some links to get you started:

- http://crunchbang.org/about
- http://crunchbang.org/forums